# LINQ To SQL Weird Join Issue

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, inner-join

I have a simple database with two tables. Users and Configurations. A user has a foreign key to link it to a particular configuration.

I am having a strange problem where the following query always causes an inner join to the Configuration table regardless of the second parameter value. As far as I can tell, even though the "UserConfiguration =" part of the object initialisation is conditional, LINQ doesn't see that and determines that a relationship is followed in any case.

If I actually remove that last initialisation, the whole thing works as expected. It doesn't inner join when loadConfiguration == false and it does join when loadConfiguration == true.

Anyone got any ideas about this? Is this syntax just not going to work? The only thought I have now is to wrap the return in a basic if statement - I just wanted to avoid the duplicated lines.

```
public UserAccount GetByUsername(string username, bool loadConfiguration)
{
    using (Database database = new Database())
    {
        if (loadConfiguration)
        {
            DataLoadOptions loadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
            loadOptions.LoadWith<User>(c => c.Configuration);
            database.LoadOptions = loadOptions;
        }

        return (from c in database.Users
                where c.Username == username
                select new UserAccount
                {
                    ID = c.ID,
                    ConfigurationID = c.ConfigurationID,
                    Username = c.Username,
                    Password = c.Password.ToArray(),
                    HashSalt = c.HashSalt,
                    FirstName = c.FirstName,
                    LastName = c.LastName,
                    EmailAddress = c.EmailAddress,

                    UserConfiguration = (loadConfiguration) ? new ApplicationConfiguration
                    {
                        ID = c.Configuration.ID,
                        MonthlyAccountPrice = c.Configuration.MonthlyAccountPrice,
                        TrialAccountDays = c.Configuration.TrialAccountDays,
                        VAT = c.Configuration.VAT,
                        DateCreated = c.Configuration.DateCreated

                    } : null

                }).Single();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Martin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think it will work like that.

I suggest splitting it into 2 distinct queries.

There are probably better ways, but it would require more 'plumbling'.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this will not work. I've run into similar issues many times. The reason for that has to do with expressions at compile time vs. conditions at run-time.

You could do 2 queries or if you don't mind joining to configuration regardless of loadConfiguration parameter, you could use:

```
var q = (from c in database.Users
                where c.Username == username
                select c).Single();
```

and then use Linq-to-Objects on the result.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Replace .Single() with SingleOrDefault() and Linq will switch to a left outer join. I don't know if in your case it will do it, but in some cases it does.</strike>

Edit dint's see the Single was for the entire query and not for the configuration part:

try this:

```
     UserConfiguration = (loadConfiguration && c.Configuration != null) ? new ApplicationConfiguration
     {
          ID = c.Configuration.ID,
          MonthlyAccountPrice = c.Configuration.MonthlyAccountPrice,
          TrialAccountDays = c.Configuration.TrialAccountDays,
          VAT = c.Configuration.VAT,
          DateCreated = c.Configuration.DateCreated
      } : null
```